# Subsetting data with specific values in glm function

Tags: r

I need to examine expenditure for specific incomes of $20K and 40K. My glm() works, but when I add subset, I get an error:

```
glm(district21$expend ~ 1 + income, family = gaussian(link = "identity"),data = district21, subset = income == 20000)
```

> Error in glm.fit(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0), weights = NULL, start = NULL,  : object 'fit' not found
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In glm.fit(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0), weights = NULL, start = NULL,  :
> no observations informative at iteration 1
> 2: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge

I'm also wondering how to specificy incomes above or below the median in the subset arguement? i.e.

```
glm(district21$expend ~ 1 + income, family = gaussian(link = "identity"),data = district21, subset = income > median())
```

Answer (score 0):

Subset needs to be a logical vector. So try this:

`glm(expend ~ 1 + income, family = gaussian(link = "identity"), data = district21, subset = district21$income == 20000)`

To subset for values greater than the median try:

`subset = district21$income > median(district21$income)`

---

Alternatively you can use `tidyverse` with piping to subset the data ahead of time:

```
library(tidyverse) 

dplyr::filter(district21, income == 20000) %>% 
   glm(expend ~ 1 + income, family = gaussian(link = "identity"), data = .)

dplyr::filter(district21, income > median(income)) %>% 
   glm(expend ~ 1 + income, family = gaussian(link = "identity"), data = .)
```